# Estimate time spent on Git project with grep

Tags: grep, git

Consider a Git log:

```
commit 4d6b30238fbfc972ea4505cadf43abd316506d9e
Author: Dotan Cohen <dotancohen@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 11 22:41:21 2016 +0200

    Final foobar version

commit 4d6b30238fbfc972ea4505cadf43abd316506d9e
Author: Dotan Cohen <dotancohen@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 11 19:11:51 2016 +0200

    Working foobars

commit 4d6b30238fbfc972ea4505cadf43abd316506d9e
Author: Dotan Cohen <dotancohen@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 11 10:31:37 2016 +0200

    Broken foobars

commit 4d6b30238fbfc972ea4505cadf43abd316506d9e
Author: Dotan Cohen <dotancohen@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 10 21:47:22 2016 +0200

    Added foobars

commit 4d6b30238fbfc972ea4505cadf43abd316506d9e
Author: Dotan Cohen <dotancohen@foobar.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 10 11:54:12 2016 +0200

    Preparation for foobars
```

**How might I get the first and last time from each commit message for each day, then do a bit of math and estimate the total time spent?** Something like this:

```
Date:   Mon Jan 11 22:41:21 2016 +0200
Date:   Mon Jan 11 10:31:37 2016 +0200
TOTAL A:           12:09:44

Date:   Mon Jan 10 21:47:22 2016 +0200
Date:   Mon Jan 10 11:54:12 2016 +0200
TOTAL B:           09:53:10

TOTAL: 22:02:54
```

For purposes of this issue, we can assume that all commits were done by the same person. Note that there can be an arbitrary amount of commits per day, and an arbitrary amount of days that may span different months or year boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Perl code should get you very, very close to what I think you want. If you're not familiar with Perl, you'll need to install the `DateTime::Format::Strptime` module from CPAN... `cpan install DateTime::Format::Strptime`.

Then, output your git log to a file `git log > git.log`.

After that, paste the following code into a file, put the log file in the same directory, and run it.

Not my prettiest or most efficient code, but I only had a few minutes to put something together.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $log = 'git.log';

open my $fh, '<', $log or die $!;

my %dates;
my @order;

while (<$fh>){
    if (/Date:\s+(.*?)(\d{2}:.*)/){
        push @order, $1 if ! $dates{$1};
        push @{ $dates{$1} }, "$1$2";
    }
}

my $letter = 'A';
my $total_time = DateTime::Duration->new;

for my $day (@order){

    my $start = $dates{$day}->[0];
    my $end   = $dates{$day}->[-1];

    my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern  => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt1 = $parser->parse_datetime($start);
    my $dt2 = $parser->parse_datetime($end);

    my $total = $dt1 - $dt2;
    $total_time = $total_time + $total;

    print "$start\n$end\n";

    print "Total $letter:\t";
    print join ':', ($total->hours, $total->minutes, $total->seconds);
    print "\n\n";

    $letter++;
}

print "Total time overall: ";
print join ':', ($total_time->hours, $total_time->minutes, $total_time->seconds);
print "\n";
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I had considered doing something similar in Python, but now is my opportunity to review my Perl!